# How to know the version of Microsoft's C runtime in use?

Tags: c++, c, windows, msvcrt

I have a program which depends on `MSVCR90.dll`, library which I'm shipping with it alongside the main executable among other things:

```
ProgramFolder\Main.exe
ProgramFolder\MSVCR90.dll
```

I wanted to know if when a new update to it is available (fixing a security issue for example) the one I supply would take precedence over the updated file in `System32` or `SxS`.

Is there a way to programatically know which version of the C runtime is being used?

Comment: According to [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astebner/archive/2010/05/05/10008146.aspx), you can check for product codes in the registry.

Comment: `VerQueryValue`, searching for `FileVersion` seems like a reasonable possibility. As to what will take precedence: I'm pretty sure that'll depend on where/how you install yours, and probably on your manifest as well.

Comment: You can't deploy msvcr90.dll in the same directory as the exe, you'll get a runtime error at startup.  It must be deployed in the side-by-side cache.  The security updates are thus ensured.

Comment: Don't ship the DLL, ship the installer for the MSVC redistributable and either run it as part of your install process or ask users to run it manually if you don't have an installer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the [executables import header](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36928/Parse-a-PE-EXE-DLL-OCX-Files-and-New-Dependency-Wa) to find which version of C runtime it has got references to. Removing it from system32 directory wont help, instead it will create a crash.